# Log in with Google on Parse (open- source server)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, google-oauth, parse-server

Now that parse server is open-source, the community behind it has already added a lot of cool features. In the original version (parse.com), we were able to log in with Facebook and Twitter. Now, we have Google, LinkedIn, GitHub, etc.

On iOS, there are 2 libraries (PFFacebookUtils and PFTwitterUtils) that allow us to easily use Facebook and Twitter authentication in our app and create PFUser object.

I would like to allow my users to log in with their Google account. As there is no PFGoogleUtils library, I haven't been able to figure out how to use the

```
+ (BFTask<__kindof PFUser *> *)logInWithAuthTypeInBackground:(NSString *)authType authData:(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *)authData
```

method of PFUser.

I tried to look at PFTwitterUtils and PFFacebookUtils but had no luck.
I even tried to log in with Twitter and Facebook **without** using PFTwitterUtils and PFFacebookUtils, but I don't know if it is a good idea.

So, is there anyone here who successfully managed to integrate Google authentication with their Parse app on iOS?

Thanks

Comment: have got any solution for the same , I am also trying to implement Google login in android. Please post you answer